# How to add a variable to custom Parsely error message?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, parsley.js

I can't seem to figure out how to add the contents of an input field to the error message for Parsely. Example:

```
// Fail particular email domains
    window.Parsley.addValidator('emailDomain',
        function (value) {
            const emailInputDomain = value.match(/@\w+[.]\w+/);
            const emailFormattedDomain = emailInputDomain[0].slice(1);
            const excludedDomains = [
                'gmail.com',
                'yahoo.com',
                'sbcglobal.net',
                'aol.com',
                'hotmail.com',
                'juno.com',
                'godaddy.com',
                'hotmail.com'
            ];
            return !excludedDomains.includes(emailFormattedDomain.toLowerCase());
        }).addMessage('en', 'emailDomain', 'Email domain is not valid');
```

I've seen examples online of using '%s' which is supposed to insert the string from the input field, but this has not yielded a value for me.

I've also tried:

```
document.getElementById('email').setAttribute('data-parsley-email-domain-message', `${value} is not valid`);
```

... which is hack-ish, and doesn't work (as the event firing affects `value` for some reason, e.x. `gmail.co` instead of `gmail.com`).

According to the API docs it doesn't seem possible to return a function from the older way of setting messages:

```
messages: function(value) {
            return { en: `${value} is not a valid email domain` }
        }
```

Any suggestions on an efficient solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsley JS - Custom error message %s format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978667/parsley-js-custom-error-message-s-format)

Answer (score 0):

You could return a "dynamic" error message is by returning a failed promise from your `validateString` method. [This example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/ajax.html) uses this technique.